# Hiding url in php error

Tags: php, html, video, session-variables

I am trying to hide video (videos/mymovie.mp4) URL so as to make video downloading difficult. I am using session id and video path to get a encrypted token. Below is my code for sublime player (video.php).

```
<?php
     include('movie_url.php');
     echo '<video id="'.$movieId.'" class="sublime" poster="'.$cover_image_path.'" width="935" height="526" title="'.$movie_title.'" data-autoresize="fit" preload="none">
           <source src="moviesessionurl.php?video='.$hash.'" />
     </video>';
?>
```

movie_url.php contains

```
<?php
    //Connect to database
    include("config.php");

    session_start();
    $sid = session_id();

    $movieId = $_SESSION['movie_id'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `movies` WHERE intMovieID = ".$movieId;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    $movie_title = $row[1];
    $movie_desc = $row[7];
    $trailer_path = $row[8];
    $movie_path = $row[9];
    $cover_image_path = $row[10];
    $still_image_path = $row[11];
    $poster_image_path = $row[12];
    $movie_duration = $row[16];

    $hash = md5($movie_path.$sid);
    $_SESSION[$hash] = $movie_path;

    mysqli_close($con);                                
?>
```

And moviesessionurl.php contains

```
<?php

    /* start the session */
    session_start();

    $path = $_SESSION[$_GET['video']];

    echo $path;
?>
```

when i run the moviesessionurl.php directly in browser i get the correct video url. But when I run video.php which contains sublime player the video doesn't play! Gives the error "Cant play video"

Please help me get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work, it is looking for video content at the url `moviesessionurl.php` I would reccomend fetching the url through an AJAX request.  Then dynamically creating the `video` element once the URL has been retreived.

Comment: Okay. So when user tries to get url from inspect element will the url be hidden from user? The main goal is to hide the url from user.

Comment: The URL will never be hidden from user, because the network panel will show an outgoing connection to the url where the video is coming from...

Comment: oops, well in that case is there any solution to at-least encrypt the url or something like that..? All I want to achieve is making it difficult for the user to download the videos I have in my website.

Comment: No matter what you do, the client will have to make a request to a URL that will server the video.  And anyone you knows how to press F12 will be able to see that URL.  You have two options, you can use flash (hides network traffic much better) or you can use your current setup, serve up a temporary url that only works once.  Then by the time the client has requested the video that URL will no longer work.  Kind of like a one off URL

Comment: Thanks MarshallOfSound, Just one last question can you please check this thread and tell me whether that works? link : http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?32608-Using-php-to-hide-video-embed-urls    How do I achieve this "read in the file at that location and output it as though it were actually the file. You player won't know the difference, and neither will the user."??

Comment: There is a function in PHP called `file_get_contents($pathToFile)` or something like that.  That links describes a process where you block direct access to the video directory.  And use the function mentioned above to get the contents of the video and send it through the one off url

Comment: Thanks a lot MarshallOfSound.